# Use NativeJSON from Rhino shell script

Tags: json, shell, rhino

I'd like to use the [NativeJSON class](https://github.com/mozilla/rhino/blob/master/src/org/mozilla/javascript/NativeJSON.java) from a Rhino shell script. The only things I can find about how to use it on the Web are from Java.

```
// Load the configuration file
load(arguments[0]);

// Extract the configuration for the target environment
print(NativeJSON.stringify(environments[arguments[1]]));
```

Any clue how I'd get at it from a Rhino shell script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NativeJSON` class is an implementation of the `JSON` object from ECMAScript 5, so you shouldn't need to do anything special. You can access it by calling `JSON.stringify(object)` or `JSON.parse(jsonString)`.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how I missed that earlier!